# Group by with a break on date

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I am trying to group data on homogenous periods of time (not sure this is clear).
Here is a simplified example of my data:

```
CREATE TABLE workhours_over_time (
             worker varchar,
             workhours integer,
             otherinfotobeignored varchar,
             startofperiod date,
             endofperiod date);

INSERT INTO workhours_over_time (worker, workhours, 
            otherinfotobeignored, startofperiod, endofperiod)
VALUES ('W1', '35', 'any info', '2020-01-01','2020-01-31');

INSERT INTO workhours_over_time (worker, workhours, 
            otherinfotobeignored, startofperiod, endofperiod)
VALUES ('W1', '35', 'any other info', '2020-02-01','2020-02-28');

INSERT INTO workhours_over_time (worker, workhours,
            otherinfotobeignored, startofperiod, endofperiod)
VALUES ('W1', '39', 'any info', '2020-03-01','2020-04-15');

INSERT INTO workhours_over_time (worker, workhours,
            otherinfotobeignored, startofperiod, endofperiod)
VALUES ('W1', '35', 'any info', '2020-04-16','2111-11-11');
```

So here is the result:

```
worker|workhours|otherinfotobeignored|startofperiod|endofperiod|
------|---------|--------------------|-------------|-----------|
W1    |       35|any info            |   2020-01-01| 2020-01-31|
W1    |       35|any other info      |   2020-02-01| 2020-02-28|
W1    |       39|any info            |   2020-03-01| 2020-04-15|
W1    |       35|any info            |   2020-04-16| 2111-11-11|
```

The result I need to obtain would group data in 3 periods: from 2020-01-01 to 2020-02-28, worker W1 works 35 hours a week. Then from 2020-03-01 to 2020-04-15 W1 works 39 hours a week. Then from 2020-04-16 to end of time, back to 35 hours.

```
worker|workhours|startofperiod|endofperiod|
------|---------|-------------|-----------|
W1    |       35|   2020-01-01| 2020-02-28|
W1    |       39|   2020-03-01| 2020-04-15|
W1    |       35|   2020-04-16| 2111-11-11|
```

I had first naive try with a simple group by:

```
select worker, workhours, min(startofperiod), max(endofperiod)
from workhours_over_time
group by worker, workhours
```

but of course, first and third period where grouped into a 2020-01-01 to 2111-11-11 period, which is not what I want.

Then I have toyed with window function, read on groups and island, but didn't find the solution...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testdb=# create table t(k text, h integer, s date, e date);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into t select 'w1', 35, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-31';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 'w1', 35, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-28';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 'w1', 39, '2020-03-01', '2020-04-15';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 'w1', 35, '2020-04-16', '2021-12-31';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select * from t;
 k  | h  |     s      |     e      
----+----+------------+------------
 w1 | 35 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31
 w1 | 35 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-28
 w1 | 39 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15
 w1 | 35 | 2020-04-16 | 2021-12-31
(4 rows)

testdb=# select row_number() over (partition by k order by s) r1,
                row_number() over (partition by k, h order by s) r2,
                t.* from t;
 r1 | r2 | k  | h  |     s      |     e      
----+----+----+----+------------+------------
  1 |  1 | w1 | 35 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31
  2 |  2 | w1 | 35 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-28
  3 |  1 | w1 | 39 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15
  4 |  3 | w1 | 35 | 2020-04-16 | 2021-12-31

testdb=# select (h, row_number() over (partition by k order by s) -
    row_number() over (partition by k, h order by s)) as group_key, t.* from t;
 group_key | k  | h  |     s      |     e      
-----------+----+----+------------+------------
 (35,0)    | w1 | 35 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31
 (35,0)    | w1 | 35 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-28
 (39,2)    | w1 | 39 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15
 (35,1)    | w1 | 35 | 2020-04-16 | 2021-12-31
(4 rows)

testdb=# with q0 as (
    select (h, row_number() over (partition by k order by s)
              -row_number() over (partition by k, h order by s)
              ) AS group_key,
           t.* from t)
select k, h,
       min(s) as s,
       max(e) as e
from q0 group by group_key, k, h order by min(s);
 k  | h  |     s      |     e
----+----+------------+------------
 w1 | 35 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-28
 w1 | 39 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15
 w1 | 35 | 2020-04-16 | 2021-12-31
```

Why does this work? In the first select with row_number, partitioning
by by both k (the worker column in your question, just shortened for
simplicity/brevity) and h gives independently-increasing sequences for
each h value for each worker. You then just subtract the worker's
overall row number sequence. Consecutive rows whose h values are the
same will have both sequences increasing by 1, so subtracting
non-hours-worked-scoped row number will give the same value for both
rows. Using both h and that subtracted value gives us a key that
identifies each contiguous set of rows for each hours-worked for each
worker; that's the group_key column in the next query.

At that point, it's a simple GROUP BY of group_key, and min/max the
start and end. And that's it.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution and the step by step explaination. Notice I'll also will have to handle the case of gaps between periods, so I will probably need to mix you solution with the lag solution of the other answer by bbaird.

Comment: Just to be complete: I added "e-lead(s) over (partition by k order by s)" to the group_key, to handle the case of gaps betwwen periods. Many thanks to both of you AdmaKG and @bbaird

Comment: Actually gaps was a bit more complicated. I ended up with: "with q0 as (
 select (sum(start_of_period) over (order by s),
         rn - rn2,
         h) as group_key,
         * 
 from ( 
  select 
         case when s - interval '1' day = lag(e) over (partition by k order by s) then 0 else 1 end as start_of_period, 
         row_number() over (partition by k order by s) rn,
         row_number() over (partition by k, h order by s) rn2,
         t.* from t
  order by e) q)
select k, h,
       min(s) as s,
       max(e) as e
from q0 group by group_key, k, h order by min(s);"

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most straightforward way to do this (edited to handle gaps):

```
SELECT
  Worker
 ,WorkHours
 ,startofperiod
 ,LEAD(priorend,1,'2111-11-11') OVER (Partition By Worker ORDER BY startofperiod) AS endofperiod
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Worker
     ,startofperiod
     ,endofperiod
     ,LAG(endofperiod) OVER (PARTITION BY Worker ORDER BY startofperiod) AS priorend --Get prior end date in case of gap
     ,WorkHours
     ,CASE
        WHEN WorkHours <> LAG(WorkHours,1,-1) OVER (PARTITION BY Worker ORDER BY startofperiod) THEN 'Y'  --If hours change
        WHEN LAG(endofperiod + Interval '1 DAY') OVER (PARTITION BY Worker ORDER BY startofperiod) <> startofperiod THEN 'Y'  --If gap
        ELSE 'N'
      END AS Change_Ind
    FROM
      workhours_over_time
  ) summary
WHERE
  Change_Ind = 'Y'
```

Returns:

```
Worker  |   WorkHours   |   startofperiod   |   endofperiod
W1      |   35          |   2020-01-01      |   2020-02-29
W1      |   39          |   2020-03-01      |   2020-04-15
W1      |   35          |   2020-04-16      |   2111-11-11
```

This will handle gaps as long as your intervals are correct (in your example they are not as 2020 is a leap year).  You could change the logic to `LAG(endofperiod + Interval '2 DAYS') OVER (PARTITION BY Worker ORDER BY startofperiod) < startofperiod` or just fix the end dates.

Comment: Great, thanks. But you're right, there might be gaps between periods... I'll have to handle that.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't that much work.  Do note this solution does not require temp tables or reading the data more than once (it will require at most two sorts) and can easily be turned into a view for reuse.